# How to add TM symbol as a superscript to button text in vb6.0

Tags: vb6

I want to add TM symbol as a superscript to button text. Like "DemoTM" text and TM should be superscript of Demo text.

Any Solution would be great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The Unicode superscript trademark is U2122 so

```
Button.Caption = "Demo" & ChrW$(&H2122)
```

You must obviously use a font that contains this glyph, for example *MS Sans Serif* does not, *Segoe UI* does.

Comment: Thanks.Its Working :)

Comment: Plus one. You must also use a code page that supports this symbol.

Answer (score 0):

No need to do this at run time.

Choose a Command button font that supports this symbol.  Then in the Properties pane you can directly paste `Demo™` for the `Caption` property's value.

If need be you can copy the character from the Character Map applet.

You can also paste this value into a source String literal if you want to do it at run time:

```
Command1.Caption = "Demo™"
```

No need for further gyrations.